# Commit/rollback using java from jsp Page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, commit, rollback

I call various java class file for  inserting data to tables from jsp page. sometime the datas are not inserted in all tables. So, it create integrity how to avoid this problem using commit/roll back  from jsp page

Comment: Post some code and we'll help you.

Comment: generally it is handled by business transaction in your service methods

Answer (score 3):

JSPs should not connect to a database and do such logic.  They're for rendering the view - that's all.

Put a servlet in between the JSP and the database.  Let the servlet validate and bind input parameters to objects, route requests to other objects to fulfill the request, add objects to response scope, and determine the next view.  It's called Model-2 MVC.

You're probably putting scriptlet code into your JSP.  This is a 1998 style that has been largely discredited.

A better solution is to learn JSTL and keep all scriptlet code out of your JSPs.  It'll also force you to move logic out of the page and onto the server side where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

use try catch and if-else statement to check whether the data insert properly
and use rollback if there is error during the insert transaction.

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=dbname;user=username;password=password";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

conn.commit();
}
catch(Exception e) {
if(!conn.isClosed()){
conn.rollback();
}
System.out.println(e);
}
finally{
if(!stmt.isClosed()){
stmt.close();
}
if(!conn.isClosed()){
conn.close();
}
}
```

or try to use JSTL to make it easier
Watch [JSF Framework Tutorials](http://youtu.be/IWHqaUE6qzU)